# Flash error 1084: "Syntax error"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hi I'm getting two error messages in Flash when using actionscropt 3.0

```
"Topbar,Layer 'Action Layer',Frame 1,line 12 1084: syntax error: expection semicolon before add.
"Topbar,Layer 'Action Layer',Frame 1,line 12 1084: syntax error: expection rightbrace before semicolon
```

Here is my code could anyone give some insight to what is actually happening thanks and help on rectifying the issue thanks.

```
clip = Number(random(7)) + 1;
while (Number(clip) <= 7)
{
   clip = Number(clip) + 1;
   Scale = Number(random(80)) + 1;
   setProperty("/star", _x, Number(random(800)) + 10);
   setProperty("/star", _rotation, Number(random(330)) + 50);
   setProperty("/star", _xscale, Scale);
   setProperty("/star", _yscale, Scale);
   setProperty("/star", _y, Number(random(800)) + 50);
   n = Number(n) + 1;
   bn = "star" add n;
   duplicateMovieClip("star", bn, n);
   set(bn add ":n", n);
} // end while
clip = "0";
```

Comment: Is this as3 or as2? Either way the problem is on this line : `bn = "star" add n;` and this line : `set(bn add ":n", n);`. There should probably be some kind of operator between `"star"` and `add` and `n`, I'm guessing a `+`

Comment: this was legacy code already when actionscript 2 was introduced, meaning that this code is probably 10+ years old. it's about time to rewrite it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you got this syntax from:

```
bn = "star" add n;
```

But I suppose what you mean is

```
bn = "star" + n;
```

That's what causes the error message.

I'm also really surprised you don't get more error messages than that, since both `setProperty` and `duplicateMovieClip` have been deprecated as of AS3.  Also, all the properties that used to start with an underscore (_x, _y, etc.) have been renamed.

Perhaps it would be wise to read up on what changed with ActionScript 3 before you continue - otherwise you will have a really hard time.

Comment: It's Macromedia Flash 4 (1999, I believe) syntax: while very old for browser development, it has been quite common until some years ago, when it was used as a basis for Flash Lite 1.1 plugin.

Comment: Yeah, I remember it had all sorts of inconvenient text based operations, like `eq` for "equals" and such...  Painful. I am still a bit puzzled that anyone would use it to start with (or revisit) Flash development today - instead of just going through an AS3 tutorial.

Comment: I remember people doing all sort of things with that language   :-)   This is still done with it: http://www.ferryhalim.com/orisinal/

Comment: Amazing.  AS2 must have been around for ... oh, that's right: 8 years (MX2004).   Wow.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is in AS2, goto your publish settings and change your script to AS2, below is the edit of your Script.

```
clip = Number(random(7)) + 1;
 while (Number(clip) <= 7)
 {
 clip = Number(clip) + 1;
 Scale = Number(random(80)) + 1;
 setProperty("/star", _x, Number(random(800)) + 10);
 setProperty("/star", _rotation, Number(random(330)) + 50);
 setProperty("/star", _xscale, Scale);
 setProperty("/star", _yscale, Scale);
 setProperty("/star", _y, Number(random(800)) + 50);
 n = Number(n) + 1;
 bn = "star" + n;
 duplicateMovieClip("star", bn, n);
 set(bn + ":n", n);
 } // end while
 clip = "0";
```

As mentioned i think you should goto Adobe Docs to check their changes from AS2/AS3, their are many changes including not allowing code or sdcripts directorly placed on symbols and buttons, Property names have been changed aswell:example:

```
_root // can no longer be targeted in this syntax
_xscale = scaleX // the underscores have been removed
                 // and the property names have been changed
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: is there a way of having both as i already have actionscript 3.0 controlling another part already, either that how would i go about converting it to actionscript 3.0?

Comment: yes this is possible but not in the same swf/movie. so what you will do is load a swf inside the other